# do checked exceptions happen at run-time?

Tags: java, exception, unchecked, runtimeexception

I am confused with the naming of runtime exception of java. 
Those checked exceptions, like SQLexception, also happen during the execution of a program.
Why only those unchecked ones called runtime exception?
It is probably I have misunderstanding of "runtime".

Thank you for any advices.

Answer (score 5):

I can understand your confusion. All exceptions occur at runtime!

The only reason I can come up with for naming the class that way, is that it clarifies that it is an exception that **doesn't have to be dealt with at compile time**.

As opposed to all other so called "checked" exceptions, `RuntimeExceptions` doesn't require the programmer to *declare* the exception to be thrown using a `throws` clause.

Answer (score 2):

`RuntimeException` is a subclass of `java.lang.Exception`.  `RunTimeExceptions` are almost always the result of a programming error or/and invariants not being met (Nulls being passed when they shouldn't), so you do not have to catch them like `java.lang.Exception` (which is Checked Exceptions).  You don't catch them because there's little the Run Time system could do to recover.

I think the phrase runtime just means they happen when the program is running (obviously!!) and crucially **the compiler doesn't force checks to be built into the code as with Checked Exceptions**.  I think it's an example of where it's difficult to name a class appropriately e.g. I guess they could have Exceptions unchecked by default and called it Exception.  Then subclassed it to provide CheckedException - everyone calls java.lang.Exception a Checked Exception, but it's not clear from the Class Name.  But they didn't and we have:

```
> java.lang.Exception is referred to as "Checked Exception" 
> java.lang.RuntimeException is referred to as "Unchecked Exception"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the naming is a bit confusing but it reflects the nature of an Exception being handled, not its time of occurrence.

**All the exceptions occur at runtime**. However, you are forced to handle the behavior of your program yourself for a specific type of exceptions i.e. CheckedExceptions. The reason is that these types of exceptions are more likely to occur. Example FileNotFoundException.

On the other hand, UnchekedExceptions[aka RuntimeExcetions] are less likely to occur and the programmer is not forced to handle those while writing the program. Ex: ArithmeticException.